# R: based on consecutive values in two rows, populate a third

Tags: r

I have a feeling there's a `dplyr` solution to this, but I can't quite get there.

I have a data frame:

```
Name     Job     ID1     ID2
Name1    Job1    ID1a    ID2a
                 ID1a    ID2a
Name2    Job2    ID1b    ID2b
Name3    Job3    ID1c    ID2c
```

Whenever there's a repeat of the ID1 and ID2 column values, I want to insert a string called 'wait'. So the final data frame should look like this:

```
Name     Job     ID1     ID2
Name1    Job1    ID1a    ID2a
         wait    ID1a    ID2a
Name2    Job2    ID1b    ID2b
Name3    Job3    ID1c    ID2c
```

There are tens of thousands of rows in my data frame. These repeat IDs occur fairly frequently. I want to insert the same 'wait' string every time ID1 and ID2 are repeated a second time. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="Name     Job     ID1     ID2
Name1    Job1    ID1a    ID2a
NA       NA      ID1a    ID2a
Name2    Job2    ID1b    ID2b
Name3    Job3    ID1c    ID2c", header=TRUE)
```

You can use `data.table::rleid` to group consecutive duplicated ID values

```
library(dplyr)
ans <- 
  df %>%
    group_by(G = data.table::rleid(paste(ID1, ID2))) %>%
    mutate(Job = c(head(Job, 1), rep("wait", times=n()-1))) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-G)
ans

   # Name  Job  ID1  ID2
# 1 Name1    1 ID1a ID2a
# 2  <NA> wait ID1a ID2a
# 3 Name2    2 ID1b ID2b
# 4 Name3    3 ID1c ID2c
```

Comment: How do you keep R from printing the result? It runs out of space after 10,000 columns.

Comment: This will not test for sequential duplications. The duplicated function is not the same as the rle function.

Comment: @42 I only want this to happen for sequences of 2, not 3 or more.

Comment: I'm accepting this based on the previous answer, which did exactly as I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[seq_len(.N) > 1], .(rleid(ID1, ID2))]$V1, Job := 'wait']
df
#    Name  Job  ID1  ID2
#1: Name1 Job1 ID1a ID2a
#2:  <NA> wait ID1a ID2a
#3: Name2 Job2 ID1b ID2b
#4: Name3 Job3 ID1c ID2c
```